# 3D printer Arduino sketch

Tags: arduino-uno, sketch

I'm building an automatic warehouse system using 3 nema17 stepper motor. My problem is to move the motors with precision, since I do not have any kind of encoder on the motor and so I cannot know the position of the axes. I tought that the system could be similar to a 3d printer, since neither 3d printers have encoder on the motor. Where can I find a sketch for Arduino of a 3d printer, to understand how they work? How do they move with such precision without any kind of sensor?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With stepper motors you don't need any form of encoder. Only a limit switch.

A stepper moves in steps - you tell it how many steps to move. As long as you know where you started from (which is what the limit switch is for) then you can always know exactly where you are.

If you told the stepper to move 10 steps clockwise you know the stepper has moved 10 steps clockwise. If you then move 10 steps anti-clockwise, you will be back where you were.

All you need to do is count.